# having different themes for different classes in flutter

Tags: flutter, themes

I'm making a multiscreen simple app on fluter, the first screen is the home page and it has two options, each option makes the user to navigate into specific screen. My question is I want each screen to have different theme. How can I do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each screen inside [Theme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme-class.html),

```
Theme(
      data: ThemeData(// Your theme here
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          accentColorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
          primaryColor: Colors.grey,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white)),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Portfolio app - Made with flutter"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: ,
.......
```